# How can I compile some parts of C++/CLI code as Native and some part as Managed?

Tags: interop, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I am calling LoadTypeLib for loading unmanaged type libraries in C++/CLI. I need to compile some code areas as managed and some code areas as unmanaged (native) and form a mixed mode class library as executable.

What part do I need to be managed and unmanaged (native) to compile as managed and native respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`#pragma managed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0adb9zxe(VS.80).aspx)

Prefer using `#pragma managed` with push and on/off, then pop, `#pragma unmanaged` is actually quite useless.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use #pragma managed - it's considered "evil" and may cause problems with DLL init/shutdown.

I would recommend explicitly compiling some files as managed (/clr), and some as native (without /clr). You can also have two pre-compiled headers - one for managed, one for native.